# Testng get parallel execution method logs separately

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng, remotewebdriver

I have used onTestSuccess, OnTestFailure for Test case execution results. I am able to report my Test case is pass or fail.

```java
if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
//
} else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
//
}else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
//
}
```

But I also need to capture logs for each method separately.. that should not overlapping with other thread logs.

```java
@Test
public void test001() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Test001");
}

@Test
public void test002() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Test001");
}
```

Can someone help or suggestions ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and enhance your post to get more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it very easily. But the only caveat is that you would need access to the `ITestResult` object of a test method (`@Test` method) to get hold of its logs. All you need to do is, use `Reporter.log()` to log messages and then use `Reporter.getOutput()` to retrieve the logs.

Here's a sample that shows this in action.

Here's how the test class would look like.

```java
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(TestCaseLogPrinter.class)
public class TestClassSample {
    @Test
    public void test001() {
        Reporter.log("Test001 : This is first message", true);
        Reporter.log("Test001 : This is second message", true);
    }

    @Test
    public void test002() {
        Reporter.log("Test002 : This is a random message", true);
        Reporter.log("Test002 : This is another random message", true);
    }
}
```

Here's a listener that retrieves the logs

```java
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class TestCaseLogPrinter extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
        System.err.println("Printing the test method logs " + asString(Reporter.getOutput(tr)));
    }

    private String asString(List<String> output) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String each : output) {
            builder.append(each).append(", ");
        }
        //Removing the last ","
        return builder.toString().substring(0, builder.length() - 2);
    }
}
```

Here's how the suite xml file looks like :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="49493003_Suite" parallel="methods" verbose="2">
    <test name="49493003_test" verbose="2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn49493003.TestClassSample"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And here's the console output

```
... TestNG 6.14.3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
Test001 : This is first message
Test002 : This is a random message
Test001 : This is second message
Test002 : This is another random message
Printing the test method logs Test001 : This is first message, Test001 : This is second message
Printing the test method logs Test002 : This is a random message, Test002 : This is another random message
PASSED: test001
PASSED: test002

===============================================
    49493003_test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
49493003_Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also retrieve log by `AfterMethod` of `TestNG`, like wise :

```
@AfterMethod
public void calltestStatus(ITestResult result) throws IOException
{
    testStatus(result);     
}

public void testStatus(ITestResult result) throws IOException
{
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        System.out.println("");     

    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
        System.out.println(""); 

    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        System.out.println(""); 

    } else {
        System.out.println(""); 
    }
}
```

Where testStatus is user defined function which handle each and every pass/fail status of Test method, which has been called on `AfterMethod` so after completing each Test it will come through and return Status.