# How to get logs for each test tag in a file in parallel run in Selenium which is running based on test parameter

Tags: selenium, logging, parallel-processing

I have a `testng.xml` which will create a Claim for 2 companies parallel, the parameter here is company name. A gist of test tags in `testng.xml` are as below:

```xml
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Test1">
    <parameter name="TestParam" value="CompanyName1" />
    <classes>
      <class name="CreateClaim" />
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Test2">
    <parameter name="TestParam" value="CompanyName2" />
    <classes>
      <class name="CreateClaim" />
    </classes>
  </test>
```

When I run this `testng.xml`, logs are generated haphazardly, mixing the logs of two test tags.

Is there any way in which I can save the logs of first test tag in one file and second test tag in other file?

It will be easy for us to check logs of each company specifically.

Comment: You can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493003/testng-get-parallel-execution-method-logs-separately)

Comment: Thank you so much Madan for the post provided. It is solving our problem